# Implicit function theorem with continuous dependence on parameter

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, banach-spaces, implicit-function-theorem, hilbert-manifolds

Let $X,Y$ be Hilbert spaces and $P$ a topological space$^1$ and $p_0\in P$.

Let $f:X\times P\to Y$ be a *continuous* map such that
for any parameter $p\in P$,  $f_p:= f|_{X\times \{p\}}:X\to Y$ is *smooth*.
Suppose also that $f_p\to f_{p_0}$ in $C^3_{loc}(X,Y)$ for $p\to p_0$ (i.e. once we fix an arbitrary compact $K\subset X$, we have uniform convergence in $C^3$-norm over it)

Suppose that $Df_{p_0}(x_0):X\to Y$ is an isomorphism, we would like to prove that under these assumptions there exists a continuous  implicit function, i.e.

> Show that exists $U_{x_0}\times U_{p_0}\subset X\times P$ product neighbourhood of $(x_0,p_0)$ and *continuous* function $x:U_{p_0}\to U_{x_0}$ such that the zero locus of $f|_{U_{x_0}\times U_{p_0}}$ is the graph of $x$, $\{(x(p),p)\ | \ p\in U_{p_0}\}$.
> If false please provide an example

Notice that the existence of the neighbourhood is already a difficult part. Indeed $C^1_{loc}$ convergence implies that there is $U_{p_0}$ such that for any $p\in U_{p_0}$, $Df_{p}(x_0)$ is isomorphism so we can apply the inverse function theorem but the size of the "inversion"-neighbourhood can shrink to zero as $p\to p_0$.
In order to prevent this, I thought to use the  $C^3_{loc}$ convergence, because we can estimate the radius of the neighbourhood using the second derivative in a neighbourhood of $x_0$, however the convergence is only on compact sets therefore I do not know how to use it to produce a bound for $D^2f_p(x)$ for $\|x-x_0\|<r$.

For the continuity I hope that somebody knows a version of the inverse function theorem or contraction principle that works in this non-smooth setting, unfortunately $C^r_{loc}(X,Y)$ is not even a metric space for $X,Y$ infinite dimensional.

$^1$ I am interested in the case where $P$ is a finite dimensional manifold so feel free to assume so if you can say something about this situation.

Comment: The paper of Albert Nijenhuis titled Strong derivatives and Inverse mappings in American Mathematical Monthly volume 81 no 9 yr 1974 pages 969-980 maybe relevant.

Comment: Can you assume $P$ is first countable?

Comment: @PietroMajer That's fine with me, the application I have in mind takes $P $ as a finite dimensional manifold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming $P$ first countable, the standard contraction principle and elementary bounds are sufficient to conclude. You do not need higher regularity:

*Let $X$, $Y$ be Banach spaces, $P$ a  topological space, $f:X\times P\to Y$. Assume that*

*i. $f:X\times P\to Y$ is continuous;*

*ii.  $f(\cdot,p):X\to Y$ is differentiable, for any $p\in\ P$.*

*iii. $f(x_0,p_0)=0$ and $D_1f(x_0,p_0)$ is invertible.*

*iv. $D_1 f :X\times P \to L(X,Y)$ is continuous *in the pair*  at $(x_0,p_0)$.*

**Proof:** Let $L:=[D_1f(x_0,p_0)]^{-1}\in L(Y,X)$, and define $g:X\times P\to X$ by $g(x,p):=x-Lf(x,p)$, so that $f(x,p)=0$ iff $x=g(x,p)$. Since $D_1g(x_0,p_0)=0$, and (by iv) $D_1g$ is continuous at $(x_0,p_0)$, there are $r>0$ and a nbd $U$ of $p_0$ in $P$ such that $\|D_1g(x,p)\|\le 1/2$ for all $x\in \overline B(x_0,r)$ and $p\in U$, which implies that for all $p\in U$ the maps $g(\cdot,p)$ are $1/2$ Lipschitz. Since $g(x_0,p_0)=x_0$ and $g$ is continuous,  choosing a smaller $U$ we may also assume $\|g(x_0,p) -x_0\|\le r/2$. Then for all  $x\in \overline B(x_0,r)$ and $p\in U$ we have
$$\|g(x,p)-x_0\|\le \|g(x,p) -g(x_0,p)\|+\|g(x_0,p) -x_0\|\le \frac12\|x-x_0\|+\frac r2\le r.$$
So for all $p\in U$, the closed ball $\overline B(x_0,r)$ is invariant for  the contraction  $g(\cdot,p)$, which has therefore a unique fixed point $x=\xi(p)$ in $\overline B(x_0,r)$. In other words, for any $(x,p)\in \overline B(x_0,r)\times U$ one has $f(x,p)=0$ iff $x=\xi(p)$. To show that $\xi:U\to \overline B(x_0,r)$ is continuous at any $p\in U$, write for $q\to p$ in $U$
$$\|\xi(p)-\xi(q)\|=\|g(\xi(p),p)-g(\xi(q),q)\|\le \|g(\xi(p),p)-g(\xi(p),q)\|+\|g(\xi(p),q)-g(\xi(q),q)\|\le$$
$$\le \|g(\xi(p),p)-g(\xi(p),q)\|+\frac12\|\xi(p) -\xi(q) \|,$$
so $\|\xi(p)-\xi(q)\|\le 2\|g(\xi(p),p)-g(\xi(p),q)\|=o(1)$ as $q\to p.$ $\qquad\square$

$$ * $$

Note that the assumption  *iv* on the map $F:=D_1g$  follows from your hypotheses, provided $P$ is assumed first countable:

*Let $X,P$ be first countable spaces, $(E,\|\cdot\|)$ a normed space, $F:X\times P\to E$. Assume that  $F(\cdot,p_0):X\to E$ is continuous at $x_0$ and $P\ni p\mapsto F(\cdot,p)$ is continuous at $p_0$ w.r.to the uniform convergence on compact sets (that is, $\|F(\cdot,p)-F(\cdot,p_0)\|_{\infty,K}=o(1)$ as $p\to p_0$). Then $F$ is continuous at $(x_0,p_0).$*

Indeed, for any sequence $(x_k,p_k)\to (x_0,p_0)$ in $X\times P$ we have

$$\|F(x_k,p_k)-F(x_0,p_0)\|\le \|F(x_k,p_k)-F(x_k,p_0)\|+\|F(x_k,p_0)-F(x_0,p_0)\|\le$$
$$\le \sup_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\|F(x_j,p_k)-F(x_j,p_0)\|+\|F(x_k,p_0)-F(x_0,p_0)\|=o(1).\qquad \square$$

Comment: Slightly confused by your $\sup$ in the last line. Do you mean $\sup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \| F(x_j, p_k) - F(x_j, p_0)\|$?

Comment: Yes of course, thank you Willie

Comment: Fantastic! every answer should be written this clearly.

Answer (score 2):

While Pietro Majer has already provided an argument and answered the questions; here is a Paper reference for a more general parameter dependent implicit function Theorem (also has Differential dependence on parameters)

https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0303320

Glöckners Paper was published in the Israel Journal of math some years later.

Addendum (from my comment below): For the continuous parameterdepence take a look at Proposition 2.1. There the parameterspace $P$ is a topological space. If I remember correctly the main thrust of the theorem was to establish various differnetiability conditions of the implicit function depending on a parameter in a very general setting. SO this is the case discussed in the introduction. However, the basis is alsways the continuous result (but thanks for catching this Warlock of Firetop Mountain).

Comment: I don't think this is relevant, the paper assumes the function is $C^1$ on the product $P\times X$ while the point of the question is to relax this regularity assumption. This generalization seems to concern the topological vector space $X$ considered.
Ps you mispelled Majer.

Comment: This is only assumed in the introduction. Look at Proposition 2.1. there the parameterspace P is a topological space. It needs to be. Helge  proves these things via induction on the order of differentiability. I must admit nevertheless that 2.1 is hard to stomach as it is vert technical to cover all sorts of fringe cases. Sorry for the misprints, typing om my phone and the spellcorrection is feeling zealous.